# No ID in ASP Control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET site created by someone else.  There is this GridView that I want to have a static header for.  To do this, I need to know the ID of this control so I can manipulate it using Javascript.  The ID is set in the .ASPX file (ie. `<asp:GridView ID="GridView1">`).  However, when I look at the generated HTML, the table corresponding to the GridView has no ID tag!  It just appears as `<table>` with some other attributes.  Is it possible that the ID was suppressed somewhere else in the code?

Thanks

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using?

Comment: Don't forget to insert `runat="server"` in `<asp:GridView>` tag.

Comment: I'm using .NET 3.5.  I have the runat="server" attribute (sorry, didn't include it in my original quest) but it still doesn't generate the ID for the table!

Comment: Could you please post the markup of the GridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the tag also includes runat="server" and set the ClientIDMode="Static" so the ID isn't changed by ASP.NET:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Comment: I'm using .NET 3.5 and I don't believe it supports ClientIDMode.  Is there some way to force the controller to have a certain ID?

Comment: In 3.5 it will have an auto generated ID.  You can't force what that will be but you can output a reference to it.  In some javascript on your ASPX page, add a variable and set it to the gridview's iD like this:  var gridViewId = <%= GridView1.ID %>;

Answer (score 0):

It is not mandatory to specify ID for GridView, only runat="server" is mandatory. You might need to look at specific patters in html to be able to identify table, so that you can access it in jquery. Maybe look at parent control and if it has id, then it is your clue. So lets say table is inside some div tag with id "sample", you could find your table with jquery

```
$('div#sample table')
```